# Restrict acess to port 8000 ( Using Apache ) - Ubuntu 14.04 Lts

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache2, restrict

I am really need of the help of `Stackflow` , I'm from Brazil , so.. Sorry for my Bad English...:)

I 'm running Ubuntu 14.04 Lts Server With Apache .

I've installed EtherCalc from : https://github.com/audreyt/ethercalc

This application run at port 8000

How can I protect the access to this port Using Apache ?

When someone try access https://192.168.8.132:8000/

he must put User and Login from .htpasswd.

My apache virtual host is like this.

`<VirtualHost *:80> 
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/
<Directory /var/www/phpmyadmin>
Order allow,deny
allow from all
</Directory>`
`<Directory /var/www/phpipam>
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride all
Require all granted
</Directory>`
    `ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>`

Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redirect request coming in on port 8000 to a different virtual host and to this add tighter access restrictions.

Then proxy this virtual host to the application listening on port 8000.

Comment: Hi Alk , thanks for reply .

Could you show me a example ? please.

Comment: It's all on http://apache.org. Search for proxying and for redirection rules, as well as for "virtual host". Where as you might skip the latter if there is nothing else to do on the server.

Comment: Alk , the Ethercalc for example is running at  https://192.168.1.32:8000 , when i create some spreedsheet , so the EtherCal still like this : https://192.168.1.32:8000/newspreedsheet. But when someone try acess https://192.168.1.32:8000/newspreedsheet  , he must put user and login by .htpasswd. 

could you help with this ? this only work with Reverse proxy ?